# How to keep track of time used on Java GUI application?

Tags: java, user-interface, browser

I'm creating a Java GUI web browser for my class, and I was wondering if there was a way to measure (in some integer number of seconds, minutes, etc.) how long a particular URL is being accessed.

Comment: You're building a web browser as _homework_?

Comment: What is the class of the component used to load the HTML?  Note that some of them work asynchronously, so if you measure the time between a statement before and after the method call, it will likely be low.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use System.currentTimeMillis() upon page load completion, then passing that to a utility method (comparing the value with another call to System.currentTimeMillis()) as soon as another URL is loaded/the page is closed?

That is not an integer time that you would get with System.currentTimeMillis(); If you're dead set on an int number of seconds/minutes/etc, you can look into [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)